# NoSuchMethod: isDestroyed()

Tags: android, android-activity

I simply call **isDestroyed()** on an **Activity** and i got this ex:

```
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Activity.isDestroyed
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at hu.illion.beentaps.util.ActivityKiller.killAllPastActivites(ActivityKiller.java:16)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at hu.illion.beentaps.MapBeenActivity$1.onClick(MapBeenActivity.java:75)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
04-09 03:08:12.692: E/AndroidRuntime(13234):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got activites in a List, and i want to iterate through it and finish all of them:

```
for (Activity act : Variables.pastActivites) {
        try {

            Log.i("Killing: ", act.getLocalClassName());
            if (!act.isDestroyed()) {
                act.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                act.finish();
            }
            else
            {
                Variables.pastActivites.remove(act);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("KillerAct: ", ex.toString());
        }

    }
```

I can even read the official documentation that there is a function named isDestroyed().
What now?

Comment: i know there is isFinishing(), i never heard of isDestroyed()

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`Activity.isDestroyed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed%28%29) is available starting at API level 17. If your application settings are for a lower API, you'll get this `Exception`.

Comment: I would add that, as a rule, make sure you link against the lowest API level you plan on targeting. That will help avoid this kind of problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can write like this to avoid the problem:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    if (!act.isDestroyed()) {
        act.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        act.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check should be on Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 (as the api is available from v17)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Activity.onDestroyed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed%28%29), this is available in API Level 17 and up which is the latest Android version 4.2+

What Android version are you trying to run this code on?